cant able to buy swap or send to other account - a particular coin
I bought a coin from Dex screener , but i cant able to sell,swap & buy the coin when i am swaping it is showing me a error msg ( this transaction reverted during the simulation . Funds may be lost if submitted )
For the transactions fee i have enough SOL
I dont understand is i can swap and send all other coins but can able to send a particular coin and i am trying to swap from last 14 hrs

please share the token name/address that would help trying to find what the problem is
